# JSoup: проблема с IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, html, парсер, jsoup

Надо пропарсить страницу и взять оттуда расписание электричек. Jsoup не подходит, не знаю почему, но парсить страницу он отказывается и выдает ошибку

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Код:

```
Document doc2;
doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=16503&st2=17003&date=today").get();
Element table2=doc2.select("table.schedule_table_classic").get(0);
```

Объясните мне кто-нибудь, XML ли это и как можно извлечь расписание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот попробуйте так, у меня работает, выводит и строки и столбцы

```
    doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=16503&st2=17003&date=today")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36")
            .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
            .get();
    Element table=doc2.getElementById("schedule_table");
    Elements tr=table.getElementsByTag("tr");
    Elements td=tr.select("td");
    for(Element el:td) 
        System.out.println(el);
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` в строке `Elements tr=table_tr.getElementsByTag("tr");`
Не знаю почему у вас работает, а у меня нет. Может быть есть другой какой-нибудь способ парсирования расписания? Например на сайте есть iframe код для экспорта, можно его как-то использовать для того, чтобы вытащить расписание?

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, попробуйте сделать так    doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=16503&st2=17003&date=today")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36")
                .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
                .get();

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, для парсинга использую всегда Jsoup, т.к удобный и достаточно простой. На Java есть много готовых HtmlParserов, погуглите. Можете попробовать HtmlUnit, тоже хорошая библиотека

Answer (score 6):

Ваша ошибка говорит о том, что `doc2.select("table.schedule_table_classic")` возвращает список элементов нулевой длины, после чего вы пытаетесь взять его первый элемент, коий не существует.

**Решение:**

Ешё раз изучите целевую страницу (её код) и составьте валидное выражение для поиска нужного списка элементов.

```
Elements tableRows = doc2.getElementById("schedule_table").getElemetsByTagName("tr");
```

Comment: `Elements tableRows = doc2.getElementById("schedule_table").getElemetsByTagName("tr");`
Ошибка - `Cannot find symbol method getElemetsByTagName(String)`

Попытался поиграться с этой строкой и получилось следущее:
`Elements tableRows = doc2.getElementById("schedule_table").getElementsByTag("tr");`

Ошибки уже никакой нет, по крайней мере при компиляции. Затем, как только дело доходит до этой строки, то возникает еще одна ошибка - `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, ну, может страница формируется после её отображения в браузере? Т.е. невозможно парсить её JSOUP-ом... Выведите в логи/файл тот html, что получаете - может там и нет искомой инфы.

Comment: Если нет, то как тогда быть? Как можно пропарсить таблицу с расписанием?

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, если есть такая проблема, то можно как-то хитро какой-то там библиотекой съэмулировать обращение к странице через браузер. Но, скорее всего, вам надо просто дотошнее изучить код страницы и попробовать вытащить хоть что-то, выводя промежуточные результаты в логи.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте с timeout.
С этим кодом, у меня все выводит.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=16503&st2=17003&date=today")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(150000).get();
    Element table = doc.getElementById("schedule_table");
    Elements tr = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
    Elements td = tr.select("td");
    for (Element el : td)
        System.out.println(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url=new URL("http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=16503&st2=17003&date=today");
HttpURLConnection request= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.setRequestMethod("GET");
request.connect();
InputStream is=request.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String rline=null;
while((rline=br.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(rline);
        }
```

и потом строку можно парсить Jsoup'ом

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document docu = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
```

и так далее

Comment: Все равно таблицы нет. Точнее таблица сама есть - ее класс, но самого расписания (времени, пункта назначения и т.д.) нет.

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, как выглядит структура xml файла?

Comment: Насколько я понял, это не xml. Скорее всего расписание появляется в результате выполнения javascript, если смотреть на названия и адреса этих скриптов. Прошу простить за мою тупость, т.к. это моя первая работа на языке java, да и потому что 1 курс еще)

Comment: @Mr.GinTR1k, ваш выше написанный код работает, страницу пропарсить можно

Comment: Парсится, но в элементе `table.schedule_table_classic` нету ни одного элемента с тэгом `tr`. Соответственно расписание не сразу загружается.